# What's the difference between constructors and passing parameters?

Tags: java, constructor

I believe I understand what constructors are now, but to me it seems they are just used for passing info to methods in another class. So why not just call a method and supply a parameter instead? Have I got this wrong?

Comment: Do you know what objects are? Constructors are used to create objects.

Comment: You could also bother to read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html I believe it is well explained there

Comment: Yes I believe I understand what an object is, i also think I get what they are used for now. Is this a good example on what I should use them for? http://pastebin.com/N0YFzQtE

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Constructors "create" objects as much as any other function sets some its fields. In reality objects are states and "creation of object" is allocation of memory, which is done before the objects is "created". What is the rest is simple update of object fields, which is done by constructor as any other function.

Comment: Right I think I got it now. Thanks a lot. I guess I will see if I am not using constructors right from my books exmaples.

Comment: @Val Except that a constructor is the only thing that can be used with `new` and is the only call (except through reflection) that leads to the creation of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors are used to create objects and are not ordinary methods. Whenever you use `new` to create an object, you actually call a constructor. For example:

```
new MyClass(); //here MyClass() is a constructor with no params
```

[Note](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html):

> Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that
>   they use the name of the class and have no return type

Comment: Yeah I get this, but what I am saying is they are ultimatley used to pass parameters to a class that can then be used by all the methods in that specific class?

Comment: @ChrisLondon How will u set the values of member variables without creating an object? If you have all static members then you can make use simple methods.

Comment: @ChrisLondon: those "parameters" usually end up defining the *state* of the object, i.e. "it's essence" or "what it is". They *could* be thought of as "just parameters to all its methods", but that's a very narrow view.

Comment: Sometimes I think programming is gunna be to hard for me... I do not quite get what you mean by thet 'state'?

Comment: @ChrisLondon: imagine two objects of the same class. What makes them different? That's the "state" of the object. You could say "all its fields" (but that a slight over-simplification).

Comment: Saying that something is not ordinary sounds important but does not answer the question why that thing is not ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right:

Constructors are always called, so these attributes MUST BE passed. If you pass this info through methods they don't have to be passed, so they could be missing.

Comment: Yes, something like that, unless you have an empty constructor or a constructor that does not have all of the parameters you need for the object's functions. But you should handle those situations somehow, or not allow a constructor missing mandatory parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are used to initialize new instance of an object, whenever you pass parameters or not.

Having parameters in a constructor is just a way to make it easy to set some initial attributes during the object initialization, which the object will most probably need in order to work as expected.

However, if those attributes weren't needed to be initialized for the correct operation of the instance object, it would make more sense not to pass them to the constructor, but just having some setters to pass them at any other time you need.

Comment: Constructors are used to *initialize* objects, creation happens *before* the constructor is called.